# what to do when prompted for ec2-user password?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d template1 -U postgres -p
```

on an 'Amazon Linux AMI 2012.03' ec2 instance. But then I get prompted for the ec2-user password:

```
[sudo] password for ec2-user:
```

but I log in using a key-pair? Is there a simple workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Question should probably be on SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: Same here, Abby.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their server does not save the password because it is not set in the .pgpass file, or the permissions are open and the file is therefore ignored.

Check the permissions on the Unix/Linux system.  On *nix systems, the permissions on .pgpass must disallow any access to world or group; achieve this by the command chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass.  If the permissions are less strict than this, the file will be ignored.

Read more about [the password file here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

Have you tried logging-in using PGAdmin?  You can save the password there, and modify the pgpass file.